# Buffer with openning and clossing boundaries in rxjava

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to work with a buffer with openning and clossing boundaries in rxjava, but I am having trouble getting it to work. What I would like to do is assuming an observable emits, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0 , 1, 3, 0, 3  I would like to end up with {0, 1, 2, 3}, {0, 1, 3}, {0, 3}.

This is the code I have so far:

```
PublishSubject openning = PublishSubject.create();
        openning.doOnNext(new Consumer() {
            @Override
            public void accept(@NonNull Object o) throws Exception {
                if(o.equals("0"))
                    openning.onNext(o);
            }
        });

        Observable<String> observableA = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).map(value -> String.valueOf(value  % 10));

        observableA.subscribe(openning);
        // TODO: Buffer by boundary
        observableA = observableA.buffer(openning, new Function<String, Observable<List<String>>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<List<String>> apply(@NonNull String o) throws Exception {
                list.add(o);
                if (o.equals("0")) {
                    return Observable.just(list);
                } else {
                    list.add(o);
                    sb.append(o);
                    return Observable.never();
                }
            }
        }, new Callable() {
            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                return list;
            }
        });
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean that the buffer should restart after encountering 3, look at the `bufferUntil` operator in the [extensions project](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowabletransformersbufferuntil) of RxJava 2.

```
compile "com.github.akarnokd:rxjava2-extensions:0.17.5"

Flowable.just("1", "2", "#", "3", "#", "4", "#")
.compose(FlowableTransformers.bufferUntil(v -> "#".equals(v)))
.test()
.assertResult(
    Arrays.asList("1", "2", "#"),
    Arrays.asList("3", "#"),
    Arrays.asList("4", "#")
);
```

For 1.x, there is the [rxjava-extras](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-extras) with [Transformers.toListUntil()](http://davidmoten.github.io/rxjava-extras/apidocs/com/github/davidmoten/rx/Transformers.html#toListUntil-rx.functions.Func1-).

Comment: Thanks, I missed the fact that there might be data between sequences that I don't want. But thanks to your suggestion I found I can do it with bufferWhile.